# Gradle does not import added dependency after build operation

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build, sentry

I am using spring-boot version 1.5.12 and gradle 5.2.1.

I have added Sentry library in my project as mentioned in its documents like below :

```
implementation 'io.sentry:sentry:1.7.23'
```

Gradle downloads the related jarFile in : `\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.sentry\sentry\1.7.23`
and also I can see it in my IDE in `External Libraries` part

then I configed it in my local environment and everything worked fine and I could see my Exception reports in Sentry dashboard.

but after that when I wanted to create a version of project for my production environment, the build operation ended successfully but this new library is not in the folder(which is the result of my build operation named `Distribution`) which contains myPro.jar and other libraries that I use , I faced the Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/sentry/Sentry
        at ir.anarestan.ipc.boot.Boot.initSentry(Boot.java:22)
        at ir.anarestan.ipc.boot.Boot.main(Boot.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.sentry.Sentry
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
```

here is my `build.gradle` file :

```
group 'pc-server'
version '0.2.1-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    <some other dependecies>

    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry:1.7.23'

}

apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'ir.anarestan.ipc.boot.Boot'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName,
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect {"$it.name"}.join(' ')
    }
}


task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File PC',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'ir.anarestan.ipc.boot.Boot'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
ext.distributionDir= "${rootDir}/dist/core"
ext.mainClassName = 'ir.anarestan.ipc.boot.Boot'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": project.name,
                "Implementation-Version": version,
                "Main-Class": mainClassName,
                "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '))
    }
    destinationDir = file("$distributionDir")
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy){
    from configurations.compile
    into "$distributionDir"
}

task copyConfig(type: Copy){
    from "$projectDir/src/main/resources/"
    into "$distributionDir"
}

task distribution(dependsOn: ['copyLibs', 'copyConfig', 'jar']){
}
```

and I face Exception here :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"ir.anarestan.ipc.repository.mongodb"})
public class Boot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Boot.class, args);
        Sentry.init();
    }
    }
```

any help would be appreciated, it has take me lots of time!!!

Comment: Any reason why you're on version 1.7? Sentry Java is on 4.2 already.: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/migration/

Comment: @BrunoGarcia because we have installed a version of Sentry on private server, and its Document says that client version should be 1.7.23 , anyway your opinion does not relate to my issue, I have tried with client version 4.3.0 but the result of  my build operation does not contains any jar file related to Sentry, do you have any opinion for this issue?

Comment: What version of Sentry on premise are you using? If it's 20.06 or newer, you can use the latest version of the Java SDK (which hopefully addresses your issue).